# Imageresizer diskcache plugin not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, disk, imageresizer

I have an .aspx page which uses the ImageResizer library to resize an image and save to a local storage and it's location written to the response.

```
ImageJob image = new ImageJob(masterPath, targetPath, new ResizeSettings("width=" + imageSize));
image.CreateParentDirectory = true;
            image.Build();
```

The diskcache plugin is set to delete the images from the local storage but nothing is happening to the images. Any ideas?

```
<diskCache dir="C$\TestUpload\Test" autoClean="false" hashModifiedDate="true" enabled="true"
subfolders="32" cacheAccessTimeout="15000" asyncWrites="false" asyncBufferSize="10485760" />

<cleanupStrategy startupDelay="00:05" minDelay="00:00:20" maxDelay="00:05"
optimalWorkSegmentLength="00:00:04"
targetItemsPerFolder="400" maximumItemsPerFolder="1000"
avoidRemovalIfCreatedWithin="00:00:10" avoidRemovalIfUsedWithin="0.00:00:10"
prohibitRemovalIfUsedWithin="00:00:05" prohibitRemovalIfCreatedWithin="00:00:05" />
```

Answer (score 1):

#### DiskCache is only for the URL API, not the Managed API. This is explained [in the DiskCache plugin description](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/diskcache).